# Why does it redirect home?

Tags: php, .htaccess

the following form on my site

```
<form name="vine" action="create.php" method="get">
<input name="id" type="text" value="Vine ID" id="id">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my .htaccess contains the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Almost everything I submit in the form takes me to create.php, except when the string I submit starts with "http://". When it starts with "http://" It redirects me to my homepage. How would I pass a full url in a $_GET without redirecting home?

Comment: Also try using `POST` instead of `GET`. Rewriting `GET` forms can get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using javascript built-in function encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent()?

That will encode url for GET request.

If you use jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click","input[type='submit']",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#id").val(encodeURIComponent($("#id").val()));
  $(this).off('submit').submit();
});
```

Comment: In case it doesn't, this function is a solution

Comment: You don't have jQuery loaded: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js

Comment: the page doesn't change when i hit submit

Comment: Updated answer. use trigger("click");

Comment: its crashing my browser now

Comment: $(this).off('submit').submit();